# How would it possible to do Hammer Curls on Gymnastic Rings?

Tags: exercise, bodyweight-exercises, exercise-technique, home-exercise, rings

I googled around but did not find any clear ways except for this one quote from 2012 where its not clear how that was being done/ practiced.

Any thoughts/ ideas on how this can be done?

Because the only way I can think of holding the rings when Curling is Parallel the body plane. How could one hold and do Hammer Curls with Rings?

> **Re: Ross, bicep curls?**
> Post by **ExplosiveStrength85** » Tue Jul 03, 2012 11:52 am

Hey guys curls have their place when needed but I would highly recommend bicep curls on gymnastic rings. Regular bicep curls don't really do too much for that top portion of lift. By using rings it reverses the role of regular curls and focuses on that top end strength. You will develop the bicep to higher degree and they are really good for developing that close end locking strength. I do regular, reverse, and **hammer curls on rings** and they will build ridiculous strength for anyone involved in grappling or arm wrestling. I do these along with heavy chins all variations. All gymnasts use the ring curls but they also do some regular curls for that lower end strength. Every exercise has its place somewhere.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing this exercise at all. Hammer curls on rings?

Answer (score 5):

I think the real question is how to do curls with rings. From there, forearm rotation will refine these to hammer curls.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HObU9DN4TQg) illustrates the technique; I'll attempt to describe it in words for future-proofing:

- Hang from the rings with feet on the ground such that the arms are held straight out from the body at a 90 degree angle, and the body is 45 degrees from the ground.
- Curl up, keeping the shoulder/arm angle constant. At the top of the curl, the rings should just pass the ears.
- For hammer curls, keep the grip vertical throughout the curl (which is a deviation from the linked video).